# Can OTRS (6) send ticket updates via REST request to other platforms especially Pipefy?

Tags: rest, otrs, ticket-system

I was wondering if OTRS has a bit of automation and send ticket updates (especially ticket status and queue status) via Rest request. I want to integrate OTRS and pipefy. The problem is that its a one way communication right now. Pipefy can send Rest request to OTRS and create ticket, but I want OTRS to send updates to Pipefy.

I saw in vague documentations about some invoker function and Web service that is written in perl that resembles the idea but little guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: The open-source version 6 does not have any invoker, but if you upgrade to Znuny LTS 6.5 an invoker is included. This should work for your requirement.